# Parse Server Will Not Connect to Self-Hosted

Tags: ios, node.js, mongodb, parse-server

I have a Ubuntu parse server hosted with MongoDB, I got my database switched over, and everything looks good. Parse Dashboard, able to get to the ports. But now when I try to get my app to start loading from there, it does nothing. I get a blank white screen and thats it. Even though all the data is now loading from my parse server self hosted anyways.

I have checked that everything is running right, port 1337 is npm start from the parse server.

This is the code I'm using:

```
let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "inSparkle"
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "CLIENT_KEY"
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "http://10.0.1.9:1337/parse"
    })

    Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(parseConfiguration)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am really confused by this because 10.0.1.9:1337 says "I dream of being a website. Please star the parse-server repo on GitHub!"

Mongo is running, as well as dashboard all on their own ports. I can even access the dashboard from the iPad I'm testing with. Just not my app.

Comment: Hi, the code that you added is only code which initialize the parse iOS SDK .. Can you please try to write some code that will execute a query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that iOS blocks your calls to Parse because the connection to your server is not secured (by default, iOS prohibits any HTTP connections without SSL/TLS encryption).

For testing purpose, you can add this to your `Info.plist`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

In the production build, `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` should of course *not* be enabled, instead you should access Parse over a secure connection.